# SharePoint 2010: Transfer calendar entries between site calendars

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to figure out how to easily transfer calendar entries between calendars on two different sites (and respective site collections).

The idea is that Site A that contains a calendar that holds the vacation days for everyone in the department.  Site B is a separate site created for a specific project.  The creator of Site B wants to efficiently transfer all calendar entries from Site A calendar onto Site B calendar for a member of the project team.  The data used to determine which calendar entries to pull from Site A can be the name of the user who originally created the calendar entry on Site A.

I'm quite new to SharePoint, so I would appreciate any guidance on how to accomplish this.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a repetitive job? What triggers this copy process?

Comment: Hello Amal,  I was hoping that the process could be triggered by the Site B creator on an as needed basis whenever a team member's vacation days need added to the calendar.

Comment: Ok Who will be doing this activity? I mean manually who is going to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Using Powershell - This is easy to develop, but require and admin to perform the action
2. By creating a visual webpart - This can be deployed into a SharePoint page so end users can initiate the synchronization

For option2, you can create following logic

1. A people picker to pick the user
2. Source Calendar URL input box
3. Target Calendar URL input box
4. A button - On click of the button get all calendar event from source for that user and add new events in the target calendar (make sure you are not duplicating)

Answer (score -1):

Save the source calendar as template with Include Content option selected and create a new calendar with this new custom template and that should bring all the entries.